# Android Google Maps v2 - Add object to marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

How can we add an object to a marker in the new **Google Maps Android API v2**?
So if we click on the `InfoWindow`, we can do something with the object?

```
public void addSpotOnMap(Spot spot) {
    getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(spot.getParseGeoPoint().getLatitude(), spot.getParseGeoPoint().getLongitude()))
            .title(spot.getName())
            .snippet(spot.getCategory())
            .draggable(false));

}
```

This sets the location, title and snippet for the object. But I want to be able to go to another activity about this specific Spot-object if I click on the `InfoWindow`

Comment: you can use [android-maps-extensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions) it extends the Marker and the Polygon classes and allows you to set and get objects from it

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not really sure if this is the correct answer, but take a look at this blogpost I made about this problem:

Since `Marker` is `final`, it's this can easily be solved by linking the data with the `Marker` in a `Map`, for example `HashMap<Marker, YourDataClass>` or `HashMap<Marker, String>`

Here's a tutorial that explains all:
http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Comment: I also didn't see any other way to do.

Comment: Please don't add link-only answers, provide a summary of the solution here on SO

Comment: Bad case to store markers in hashmap as a key.Also bad to store marker reference

Comment: @Yahor10 can you explain why this is bad, please?

Comment: When you load a lot of  markers they will change own ids, so you can not find your reference in container,also you not need to store dynamic data of markers that not visible and etc... Your marker in container will have ID = 101, but marker on the googlemap ID = 102, but it will the same marker!

Answer (score 24):

As of Play Services v9.4.0, you can now set any object directly upon a marker!

To save the data:

```
Marker marker = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lat, lng)
        .title(spot.getName());

CustomObject myData = new CustomObject();
marker.setTag(myData);
```

Then to retreive your data:

```
CustomObject myRestoredData = (CustomObject)marker.getTag(myData);
```

For more infomration on marker data, [here are the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#marker-data).

Comment: I know this is an old question but I wish they would add the userData option like they have in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try [android-maps-extensions](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions) its library where you can add object to mark by setdata method and retrieve data call method getData

[Read more](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/wiki)

```
Object getData() and setData(Object) on Marker, Circle, GroundOverlay, Polygon, Polyline or TileOverlay
```

from Gradle You may use any version of Google Play Services

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an object within the marker after adding it on the map like:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(YOUR_LANG_LAT).title(YOUR_TITLE);
Marker addedMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
addedMarker.setTag(obj);
```

Then on map click for instance you can retrieve your object as:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
    CustomObject obj = (CustomObject) marker.getTag();

    return false;
});
```