# Android Google Map multiple markers on same location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a simple app with Google Map and dynamicly loading markers. In case 2 or more markers have same lat and long only one is presented. Is there any solution for this? This is how I plot markers to map

```
private void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers, String markerIcon)
    {
        if(markers.size() > 0)
        {

            for (MyMarker myMarker : markers)
            {
                // Create user marker with custom icon and other options
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myMarker.getmLatitude().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
                markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(manageMarkerIcon(markerIcon)));

                Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
                mMarkersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could, how would you use these two overlapping markers? only the top one would be visible.
Instead, if two markers overlap, you could express the data they share in one marker that contains them both.

this answer might assist: [Android Google Maps v2 - Add object to marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884105/android-google-maps-v2-add-object-to-marker)

Answer (score 0):

Both markers are shown, but both on the same location and it seems to be only one, and if you click on them, only one info window will be presented.

If you really need to add two markers at the same location you may want to take a look at [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering). It's part of the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).

A possible workaround could be to check if there is another marker in the position you are trying to draw the marker into, and if so, move the new marker a little bit appart.