# Send argument to fragment in a listener in a loop

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

Hey Stackoverflow community,

I am working on an android app for an academic project, the goal is to retrieve data using an API and display it on a map using markers.

I would like to display some details in a fragment when the user click on the marker. I use beginTransaction and setArguments to do so and it works for one markers.
My problem is that my markers are created in a for loop and I can only retrieve the arguments from the last iteration of the loop.

Here is the loop in my mainActivity:

```
JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++ ) {
    String name = placeList.get(i).getName();
    double lat = placeList.get(i).getLat();
    double lng = placeList.get(i).getLng();
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .title());
// CustomOnMarkerClickListener(place) implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new CustomOnMarkerClickListener(place));
}
```

Here is my custom OnMarkerClickListener

```
public class CustomOnMarkerClickListener implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    JSONObject place;

    public CustomOnMarkerClickListener(JSONObject place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        InfoPanelActivity ipa = new InfoPanelActivity();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("place", place.toString());
        ipa.setArguments(args);

        if(findViewById(R.id.textView2) == null) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.info_panel_frame, ipa)
                    .commit();
        } else {
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.info_panel_frame, ipa)
                    .commit();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And here is how I get the argument in my fragment

```
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String name = args.getString("place");
        TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText("test: " + name);
```

I had really appreciate if you could help, I really don't see how to solve that problem.

Thanks

Comment: Since there can only be one `OnMarkerClickListener` set on the map, you need a way to lookup the information about a marker inside your listener instead. This suggests you need a way to tag a marker with something like an index into the JSONArray so that when it's clicked you can retrieve the data. Looking at the javadoc for `MarkerOptions`, I don't see anything that lets you attach any custom data to it (same for the `Marker` object returned from `addMarker()`), which leaves me a bit stumped and makes me wonder why Google didn't make an affordance for this...

Comment: Seems like the solution is to use your own data structure to map the `Marker` returned from `addMarker()` to some data you have. This post describes such an approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13902666/1207921

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new CustomOnMarkerClickListener(place));
```

You are re-setting the click listener, not adding another one.  The click listener is on the map itself, not individual marker.  At the end of the for loop, the click listener will have the data of "place" for only the last marker.  You need to save the place data inside of each Marker and access it in your onMarkerClick() method.

Something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++ ) {
String name = placeList.get(i).getName();
double lat = placeList.get(i).getLat();
double lng = placeList.get(i).getLng();
map.addMarker(new CustomMarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
        .place(place)
        .title());
}

// CustomOnMarkerClickListener(place) implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new CustomOnMarkerClickListener());
```

Then in your click listener class..

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
   String place = marker.place();
   ...
}
```

Comment: `MarkerOptions` does not have a `.place()` method. You appear to be suggesting writing a subclass, here named `CustomMarkerOptions`, but there is no way to retrieve such an object when the `Marker` is clicked (and `Marker` doesn't have a `.place()` method either).

Comment: I was thinking you could write a custom Marker object as well.  You could try setting the place data in .snippet() for now

Comment: If I recall correctly, the snippet text is shown in the info window of a marker, so only something meaningful to the user should really belong there.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answer and comments, they really helped me understand the problem. I was guessing it was something like that but I could not figure it out. 
I'll try the custom marker to attach my structure to it.